# The query returns more results that I have defined for it

Tags: sql, ms-access

in the code i defined for the query to show me the first 3 result

```
SELECT TOP 3 C.NameCity
FROM Users_A AS A, Cities AS C
WHERE (((A.UserEconomicStatus)="מבוסס") AND ((A.UserCity)=[C].[NumCity]))
GROUP BY C.NameCity
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;
```

but this is what the query returns
https://ibb.co/dtkjJJ
5 RESULTS

Comment: Your question has tags for **three different database products**. Which one are you using?  Which one is producing this behaviour?  Obviously not Oracle, as that's not valid Oracle syntax. Please don't use irrelevant tags to attract extra eyes to your question: it just annoys people.

Comment: And what is the link for? It's in the middle of a statement; do you really think people will click a random link from.a compete stranger?

Comment: ^ put the text of the output into the question, why do you need a screen shot for 5 strings you can obviously copy and paste in one go? Also, add the `COUNT(*)` to the select list, that might give a hint about what's going on. Finally, if this is SQL Server (I doubt it is), you need `=N'מבוסס'` instead of `="מבוסס"` so that your where clause doesn't turn into something completely unexpected (like `='?????'`).

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you are using MS Access.  In MS Access `top` acts like `top with ties`.  You need an additional key to make the sorting stable.

Something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 3 C.NameCity
FROM Users_A AS A JOIN
     Cities AS C
     ON A.UserCity = [C].[NumCity]
WHERE A.UserEconomicStatus = "מבוסס"
GROUP BY C.NameCity
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC, C.NameCity;
```